# how to save you tube videos from the library onto my computer

Tags: youtube

I have saved YouTube videos from my android phone into the YouTube library. I thought it was being saved onto my phone.

How do I save the videos from the YouTube library onto my android phone or computer?

Comment: What is exactly the " YouTube Library"?

Comment: By saying YouTube Library he might be referring to the YouTube offline mode. @Matt95

Answer (score 0):

The videos that you download in offline mode on your mobile YouTube app are saved on your device only but their extension is different and therefore they cannot be played except official YouTube application.

If you want to view the downloaded video somewhere else on your device rather than YouTube app than you need to download third party application called 'Tubemate'. Tubemate is the right choice to download YouTube videos in desired resolution. Also it gives users privilege to download videos from other sites like 'Dailymotion', 'Vimeo' and many more. Tubemate directly saves the video on your default memory location whether its internal storage or sd card.

For computer the best application used for downloading is 'IDM'. Download and run the setup according to the instructions and afterwards integrate IDM integration module extension in the browser. That's it, you are ready to go from there. Visit YouTube from the browser and when you play the repected video, direct download link through IDM will be generated. Click on that and enjoy your downloaded video whenever, wherever, however and on whatsoever platform you want.

[Tubemate android application download link](http://tubemate-youtube-downloader.en.uptodown.com/android)

[IDM pc application download link](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

The videos you saved in your device will be saved in an encrypted format which you cannot play using video players like MX player etc.., YouTube, Netflix and several other apps use encryption technique when you save the video offline.

To download YouTube videos, there are several websites/apps available.

Application: Tubemate, SnapTube.
Websites: https://www.onlinevideoconverter.com/

Answer (score -1):

From you Android device all you need to do is download Tubemate.Apk  from this like http://tubemate-youtube-downloader.en.uptodown.com/android/download

After downloading

1.Install the app
2. Search for the video you need, when you are the video
3. Click the green button on the top of the screen 
4. Select the resolution you need and download

Comment: The question noted: *How do I save the videos **from the YouTube library** onto my android phone or computer?*